# Generic data structure with a union type in Scala

Tags: generics, scala, types

I am trying to achieve something roughly as follows:

```
/* I assume that we have some types S and T */

sealed trait Container[U]
class SContainer(s: S) extends Container[S]
class TContainer[U <: T](u: U) extends Container[U]

/* this requires something more */
def invoke[U](f: String => U): Container[U]
```

Simply put, I want a `Container` class that can either hold things of type `S` or things that are a subtype of `T`. The `Container` class clearly satisfies these properties, as there are only two possible ways to construct the container.

However, now I want to create a function `invoke` that wraps a value in a container. The definition given in my example clearly does not work, as I place no restrictions on `U`.

Unfortunately thanks to type erasure we can't also define two functions:

```
def invoke(f: String => S): Container[S]
def invoke[U <: T](f: String => U): Container[U]
```

as they would have the same type during runtime.

How to express such a type constraint on `invoke`?

Comment: There is a contradiction here. You define `TContainer` to be subtype of `Container[T]`, while you wish to have `invoke` return a `Container[U]`. So first of all, you need to decide whether you want a `Container[T]` or `Container[U]`.

Comment: Whoops. You are correct, it should be `Container[U]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following could work. I don't know what your `T` and `S` are, so I'm trying with these

```
type T = AnyVal
type S = String
```

You can use a view bound:

```
object Container {
   implicit def stuffS(s: S): Container[S] = new SContainer(s)
   implicit def stuffT[U <: T](u: U): Container[T] = new TContainer(u)
}
sealed trait Container[U]
case class SContainer(s: S) extends Container[S]
case class TContainer[U <: T](u: U) extends Container[T]
```

Then your `invoke` becomes:

```
def invoke[B, A <% Container[B]](f: String => A): Container[B] = f("hallo")
```

And these calls are valid:

```
invoke(_.size)    // -> Container[T] = TContainer(5)
invoke(_.reverse) // -> Container[S] = SContainer(ollah)
```

And this is disallowed:

```
invoke(Symbol(_))
```

**EDIT**

If the you want `Container[U]` instead of `Container[T]`, it becomes simpler:

```
object Container {
  implicit def stuffS(s: S): Container[S] = new SContainer(s)
  implicit def stuffT[U <: T](u: U): Container[U] = new TContainer(u)
}
sealed trait Container[U]
case class SContainer(s: S) extends Container[S]
case class TContainer[U <: T](u: U) extends Container[U]

def invoke[A <% Container[A]](f: String => A): Container[A] = f("hallo")

invoke(_.size)      // Container[Int]
invoke(_.reverse)   // Container[String]
invoke(Symbol(_))   // forbidden
```

Comment: It seems like I have simplified my original question a bit too much, but your solution is a perfectly valid and nice one for the way I presented my question.

Comment: I know what you mean :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the definition of the container from the definition of the types that are acceptable for the container itself.

First of all let's say (for example) that S is String and T is a dummy class.

```
class A
class B extends A

type T = A
type S = String
```

Now, let's use the typeclass pattern to define S and subclasses of T as acceptable content for our container:

```
sealed class AcceptableContent[X] private() 
object AcceptableContent {
  implicit object SAcceptable extends AcceptableContent [S]
  implicit def TAcceptable[U <: T] = new AcceptableContent[U]
}
```

now the Container class can be defined like this:

```
class Container[R : AcceptableContent](content: R)
```

the context bound `: AcceptableContent` says you can accept a R only if there is an implicit AcceptableContent[R] in scope, which is what you want. 
In fact, now:

```
scala> new Container("test")
res0: Container[java.lang.String] = Container@1d1fceed

scala> new Container(new A)
res1: Container[A] = Container@631803fb

scala> new Container(new B)
res2: Container[B] = Container@67446579

scala> new Container(true) // Ok, Container accepts String, A, B but not Boolean
<console>:12: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type AcceptableContent[Boolean]
```

So, invoke now becomes:

```
def invoke[N : AcceptableContent](f: String => N) : Container[N] = new Container(f("test"))
```